# What does it mean for a matrix to change basis?

Tags: matrices, inverse, transformation

I understand what it means for vectors, i.e.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -3 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
4/3 \\
1/6 \\
-1/2
\end{pmatrix},
$$

but when it comes to representations of linear maps, i.e.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$

my intuition fails me. I have two problems with this:

1. Representations depend on 2 bases, the one from the original space and the one from the target space, so which one changes?
2. I suppose that it is very similar to the vector case, but I don't know how to proceed with the adaptation. A disregarded "thanks".

Answer (score 1):

Let $L:U \rightarrow V $ be a linear map. Then, given basis of $\{u_i\}$ of $U$, $\{v_i\}$ of $V$, the matrix $M_L$ which represents $L$ in the given bases has components $(M_L)^i_{\ j}= v^i (L(u_j))$, where $\{v^i\}$ is the dual basis of $\{v_i\}$. There is a reason for placing one index above and one below in $M_L$ but ignore it and just think of $(M_L)_{ij}$ if you are not familiar with it - or ask if you are curious.

Perhaps another wording will be clearer: the matrix associated to a linear map $L:U\rightarrow V$ with respect to the bases above has as $j$th column the components  of the image of the $j$th basis vector of the domain vector space $U$ $L(u_j)$ with respect to the basis $\{v_i\}$ of the target vector space $V$.